# MPI with class & for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I want to use MPI for parallel processing the calculation of hamiltonian paths in a graph.
So, I achieved this:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import random,time

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
my_rank = comm.Get_rank()
p = comm.Get_size()
numOfNodes = 10
numOfProblems = 11
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, numOfNodes):
        if numOfNodes > 0:
            self.numOfNodes = numOfNodes
        else:
            print("Error")

    def calculateMaxPairs(self):
        self.maxPairs = self.numOfNodes*(self.numOfNodes - 1)//2

    def generatePairs(self):
        self.calculateMaxPairs()

        self.pairs = []
        startRange = self.numOfNodes
        endRange = (self.numOfNodes - 10)*3 + 18
        numOfPairs = random.randint(startRange, endRange)

        while len(self.pairs) != numOfPairs:
            try:
                startNode = random.randint(1, self.numOfNodes)
                endNode = random.randint(1, self.numOfNodes)
                if startNode == endNode:
                    raise ValueError
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                pair = (startNode, endNode)
                invertedPair = (endNode, startNode)

                if pair not in self.pairs and invertedPair not in self.pairs:
                    self.pairs.append(pair)
        self.hamiltonianPath = []

    def generatePathLink(self):
        self.graphLink = {}
        for x in self.pairs:
            x = str(x)
            splitNode = x.split(', ')
            a = int(splitNode[0][1:])
            b = int(splitNode[1][:-1])
            try:
                if b not in self.graphLink[a]:
                    self.graphLink[a].append(b)
            except KeyError:
                self.graphLink[a] = []
                self.graphLink[a].append(b)
            finally:
                try:
                    if a not in self.graphLink[b]:
                        self.graphLink[b].append(a)
                except KeyError:
                    self.graphLink[b] = []
                    self.graphLink[b].append(a)
                finally:
                    pass

    def findPaths(self, start, end, path = []):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return [path]
        if start not in self.graphLink:
            return []
        paths = []
        for node in self.graphLink[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpaths = self.findPaths(node, end, path)
                for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)
                    if (len(newpath) == self.numOfNodes):
                        self.hamiltonianPath = newpath
                        raise OverflowError
        return paths

    def exhaustiveSearch(self):
        try:
            allPaths = []
            for startNode in self.graphLink:
                for endNode in self.graphLink:
                    newPaths = self.findPaths(startNode, endNode)
                    for path in newPaths:
                        if (len(path) == self.numOfNodes):
                            allPaths.append(path)
            return allPaths
        except OverflowError:
            return self.hamiltonianPath
        else:
            pass

    def isHamiltonianPathExist(self):
        time_start = time.clock()
        self.generatePathLink()

        if len(self.graphLink) != self.numOfNodes:
            time_elapsed = (time.clock() - time_start)
            return [[], time_elapsed]
        else:
            result = self.exhaustiveSearch()
            time_elapsed = (time.clock() - time_start)
            if len(result) == 0:
                print("There isn't any Hamiltonian Path.")
            else:
                print("Computing time:", round(time_elapsed, 2), "seconds\n")
            return [result, time_elapsed]
            comm.send(result, dest=0)
            

yes = 0
no = 0
total_computing_time = 0
for x in range(1, numOfProblems + 1):
    if my_rank !=0:
        graph = Graph(numOfNodes)
        graph.generatePairs()
        output = graph.isHamiltonianPathExist()
    else:
        for procid in range(1,p):
            result = comm.recv(source=procid)
            time_elapsed = comm.recv(source=procid, tag=12)
            total_computing_time += time_elapsed
            if len(result) == 0:
                no += 1
            else:
                yes += 1

print("Have Hamiltonian Path:", yes)
print("Don't Have Hamiltonian Path:", no)
print("Total computing time for %s problems in %s processes: %s s"%(numOfProblems, p, str(round(total_computing_time, 2))))
```

As you can see in this script, there's two sections.
The first one is where we will generate a Graph and calculate the hamiltonian paths.
The second one is where we tell the script to run this graph generating script in parallel in multiple processors.
The problem here is that it generates the graph and calculate paths in every processor, not dividing the job between them.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you use `!= 0` ? It needs `== 0` to create Graph only in first process. As for me first process should send `range(1, numOfProblems + 1)` and other process should create own `Graph` and calculate path for received values and send result back. It means that `for`-loop should be inside `if my_rank == 0:`, not outside `if`.

Comment: I think the main problem is that you expect too much - MPI will not divide job between processes automatically - you have to do this. If you what to calculate Graph for different number of nodes then you have to send different number of nodes to every process and every process has to receive it and create own Graph for own number of nodes, calculate it and send back result. Problem is when you have more values then processes because you would have to use some processes many times - and you would have to do it manually or you should use `Pool` like in modules `threading` or `mulitprocessing`.

Comment: BTW: I don't understand why you use `x = str(x)` `splitNode = x.split(', ')` `a = int(splitNode[0][1:])` `b = int(splitNode[1][:-1])` if you can do simply `a = x[0]` `b = x[1]` or even `a, b = x`